# Processing - how to add a drag facility to the graphics

Tags: processing

I am new to Processing so this question might be ... 
I want to add drag and drop facility to the graphics I generate.

I found [Processing - Mouse Functions](http://processing.org/examples/mousefunctions.html) which explains how to add dragging to a specific object yet I am looking for a general solution in which i dont have to add the dragging methods for each object i want to be able to drag around.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to encapsulate the functionality into a class you can extend.
If your graphics extend such a class, then they also become "draggable".

Here's a minimal example where the graphics are simply boxes, but extending the "draggable behaviour":

```
int nb = 3;
Box[] boxes = new Box[nb];//a list of draggable graphics, currently empty

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){
    boxes[i] = new Box();//populate the list with actual objects
    boxes[i].x = 10+110*i;//and setup their coordinates
    boxes[i].y = 100;//and dimenensions
    boxes[i].w = boxes[i].h = 100;
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0);//clear
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){
    boxes[i].update(mouseX,mouseY);//update the internal state(if it's over or not, calculate drag offset, etc.)
    boxes[i].draw();//render each graphics element on screen
  }
}
void mouseDragged(){//if the mouse is dragged
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){//for each graphics element
    if(boxes[i].isOver) {//if it's over
      boxes[i].x = mouseX-boxes[i].offx;//than drag based on the mouse position
      boxes[i].y = mouseY-boxes[i].offy;//but take te mouse offset in relation to each object into account
    }
  }
}
class Draggable{//a generic draggable template with no graphics to display
  float x,y,w,h,offx,offy;//position, dimensions and x,y offset to drag
  boolean isOver;//is the cursor over the bounding box of this object ?
  void update(int mx,int my){//let's work that out based on the mouse x and y coordinates
    isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= x+w) && (my >= y && my <= y+h));//if it's within bounds on x and y axis, then we're in the over state
    if(isOver){//if we're in the over state we can also update the mouse drag offsets
      offx = mx-x;
      offy = my-y;
    }
  }
}
class Box extends Draggable{
  void draw(){
    fill(isOver ? 127 : 255);
    rect(x,y,w,h);
  }
}
```

This would be a fun little opportunity to test an OOP concept: polymorphism

```
int nb = 6;
Draggable[] boxes = new Draggable[nb];//a list of draggable graphics, currently empty

void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){
    boxes[i] = (random(1.0) > .5) ? new Box() : new Blob();//populate the list with actual objects
    boxes[i].x = 10+110*i;//and setup their coordinates
    boxes[i].y = 100;//and dimenensions
    boxes[i].w = boxes[i].h = 100;
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0);//clear
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){
    boxes[i].update(mouseX,mouseY);//update the internal state(if it's over or not, calculate drag offset, etc.)
    boxes[i].draw();//render each graphics element on screen
  }
}
void mouseDragged(){//if the mouse is dragged
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nb; i++){//for each graphics element
    if(boxes[i].isOver) {//if it's over
      boxes[i].x = mouseX-boxes[i].offx;//than drag based on the mouse position
      boxes[i].y = mouseY-boxes[i].offy;//but take te mouse offset in relation to each object into account
    }
  }
}
class Draggable{//a generic draggable template with no graphics to display
  float x,y,w,h,offx,offy;//position, dimensions and x,y offset to drag
  boolean isOver;//is the cursor over the bounding box of this object ?
  void update(int mx,int my){//let's work that out based on the mouse x and y coordinates
    isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= x+w) && (my >= y && my <= y+h));//if it's within bounds on x and y axis, then we're in the over state
    if(isOver){//if we're in the over state we can also update the mouse drag offsets
      offx = mx-x;
      offy = my-y;
    }
  }
  void draw(){}//empty implementation to be overwritten by a subclass
}
class Box extends Draggable{
  void draw(){
    fill(isOver ? 127 : 255);
    rect(x,y,w,h);
  }
}
class Blob extends Draggable{
  void draw(){
    fill(isOver ? 127 : 255);
    ellipse(x,y,w,h);
  }
}
```

This is an idea of how implement this, but there are multiple ways of achieving this.
Have a look at the [Processing OOP tutorial](http://processing.org/tutorials/objects/) or the more in depth Java [OOP one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)
For example the above could be achieved using Interfaces or an AbstractClass.
It's up to your goals and restrictions what the best solution will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot George. I was kind of hoping that there is already something build in available or through an extension but with your post it should be easy to do it myself. Thanks again.